# Logic operator 'A doesn't imply B' using AND, OR, XOR operators

Tags: operators, logic, bitwise-operators

I have two bit masks (say *A* and *B*, and I want to know which bit of *A* is 1 where the corresponding *B* bit is 0 (and viceversa).

Of course this is implementable using conditional statements, but I don't want to iterate/shift for testing all bits of the bit mask.

The logic condition which I need is not implemented (or at least, I can't see it). Using a parallel with the logic gates, I need the operator 'A doesn't imply B' (see on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gates#Logic_gates)).

Is it possible to implement such operator using AND, OR, XOR operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the linked Wikipedia, the simplest expression is `A and (not B)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

<strike>A xor (not B)</strike>

```
A xor B
```

Analysis:

```
A  B  A xor B
0  0     0
0  1     1
1  0     1
1  1     0
```

#### Edit:

Changed it to a simple XOR, that gives the result that the question asks for. Perhaps the question is not correctly worded, as the solution seems too simple...

Comment: It is elegant. Interesting that negating the expression becomes *(not A) xor B*

Comment: just out of curiosity, how does this give where A is 1 and B is 0?

Comment: @steabert You're right. I even analysed it. Today my brain is not working. I'll be here when my neurons are connected enought.

Comment: Ok, I'm here. I've analysed *A & !B* (so I replaced the ^ with a &).

Comment: This is not even close to the correct function, which should only give 1 if A = 1 and B = 0.

Comment: @erikkallen: That's not at all how I read the question. Note the "and viceversa" in the question, which I assume means that the result should be 1 when A = 1 and B = 0 as well as when A = 0 and B = 1. The question does not make sense at all the way that you describe it.

Comment: -1 Also, with the viceverca under consideration, I would have guessed that it would come down to a simple XOR? so I reasoned that wasn't the intention...  The `A and (not B)` answer seems be simplest, since the question was to implement "A doesn't imply B".

Comment: @steabert: Yes, it comes down to a simple XOR. Perhaps that is not the desired answer, but it's the answer to the question.

Comment: @Guffa: spending some time here, I've notice that answering what the person intended to ask is more appreciated than giving the answer to what he actually asked.  However, in this case the added "I need the operator 'A doesn't imply B'" was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
A AND (A XOR B)
```

gives you a 1 where A is 1 and B is 0.

First you detect where A an B are different, then you match with where A is 1.

Comment: That's not correct. That does not give the result 1 when A = 0 and B = 1. Note the "and viceversa" in the question.

Comment: See my comment below, giving also 1 when A = 0 and B = 1 would come down to a simple XOR.  The question was eventually phrased as "A doesn't imply B" and with a reference to the Wikipedia article.  Also, your answer also gives 0 when A = 0 and B = 1 :D